# How cross validation is used with LibSVM's java library?

Tags: java, validation, machine-learning, libsvm, cross-validation

I am trying to perform k-fold cross validation with LibSVM's java library.

how far i have understood the cross validation process, the `svm_cross_validation()` method should give me the optimised values of parameters. Where `svm_cross_validation()` method doesn't return any value, instead it sets the target class labels of training data in one of the arguments.

Now I am totally confused about how to get the best values of parameters for kernel functions. It would be a great help if someone can elaborate the process of getting the best suitable parameter values performing cross validation with LibSVM's Java library.

If more information is required please comment.